# dear all now i'm facing issue with mysql workbench what should i do

Tags: mysql, sql

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:43:11 | `create function add_five (@num as int) returns int as begin return( @num+5 ) end` | Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`@num as int) returns int as begin return( @num+5 ) end`' at line 1 | 0.000 sec |

MYSQL

```sql
create function add_five (@num as int)
returns int
as 
begin
return(
@num+5
)
end;
```

Comment: `what should i do` - consult the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) regarding the `@num as int` near which the error happens, which will tell you it should be `num int`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_five (num int )
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
       RETURN num + 5;
```

[MySQL CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION add_five (num int )
    -> RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    ->        RETURN num + 5;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> select  add_five(10);
+--------------+
| add_five(10) |
+--------------+
|           15 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select  add_five(12);
+--------------+
| add_five(12) |
+--------------+
|           17 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```